# Neo4j Cypher show first and last connected node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I created a graph in Neo4j for test purposes. Graph looks like screenshot below (simplified):
[image]

What I want is the path from London to Edinburgh. For that I created following Cypher Query:

```
MATCH (start:CITY {Name: "London"})
MATCH (end:CITY {Name: "Edinburgh"})
MATCH path = (start)-[:HAS_STATION]->(:STATION)-[:BOARDS]->(:SECTION)-[:NEXT_SECTION*]->(:SECTION)-[:UNBOARDS]->(:STATION)<-[:HAS_STATION]-(end)
```

This Query leaves me with the whole path Via Section 1, 2 and 3. All I need for my result is the first and last section. If there is a transshipment in between (i.e. Glasgow), I also would need the last section before transshipment and the first after the transshipment.

In other words: I need every section that is directly connected to a station from the path. I tried out following extension:

```
with nodes(path) as nodes
unwind nodes as node
with node
where ()-[:BOARDS]->(node) or (node)-[:UNBOARDS]->()
```

But with that query extension I ended up with all Sections, since they all can either board or unboard at a specific station (even if that station is not part of the path).

Comment: How do you identify a transshipment in your model?

Comment: Check out this section from the docs (it even have similar model as yours) https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/patterns/concepts/#quantified-path-patterns

Comment: The doc examples say nothing about "transshipments". How does one determine that a "transshipment" is supposed to be made a particular station? For example, are transshipment city names provided in a list parameter, or do you look at a particular property in the DB, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

To get the first and last `SECTION` in your path, declare a variable in the node patterns either side of the `NEXT_SECTION` variable length portion:

```
MATCH (start:CITY {Name: "London"})
MATCH (end:CITY {Name: "Edinburgh"})
MATCH path = (start)-[:HAS_STATION]->(:STATION)-[:BOARDS]->
             (first:SECTION)-[:NEXT_SECTION*]->(last:SECTION)-[:UNBOARDS]->
             (:STATION)<-[:HAS_STATION]-(end)
RETURN first, last
```

Answer (score 0):

The title asks for the first and last sections.

Your text asks to find "every section that is directly connected to a station from the path." For that, we'll find the path and then filter for the station nodes.

```
MATCH (start:CITY {Name: "London"})
MATCH (end:CITY {Name: "Edinburgh"})
match path = (start)-[mid:HAS_STATION|BOARDS|NEXT_SECTION|UNBOARDS*]-(end)
with mid
where mid:STATION
return mid
```